# prevent page reload on back button in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages in jquery mobile `users.html` and `chat.html`. in `user.html` I have a `listview` created which populates on `pegeinit` event of `user.html` page, now when I click on item of listview I am loading `chat.html` via `changePage` method.

But when I press back button of `chat.html` which goes back to `user.html` then the `user.html` gets refreshed and, because of that, my listview lose the state, so I want to prevent reload when back button on `chat.html` gets pressed.

Comment: add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div.

Comment: yeah that worked but what does this attributed does , does it keep it in a cache  ?

Comment: [prefetching and caching pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)

Comment: yes, it caches pages. when using single page model, jQM keeps first page and current page in DOM. the rest are removed but their URL are kept in history.